# No 'ndk-build' in PATH, please install Android NDK and configur e properly

Tags: android, android-ndk

hi i am looking in this,
https://github.com/strazzere/android-unpacker/tree/master/native-unpacker

and as per compiling i write "make" but the error is coming

```
No 'ndk-build' in PATH, please install Android NDK and configur e properly
```

my environment variables are

```
Variable :- ANDROID_SDK_HOME
Value :- C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Variable :- PATH
Value :- %ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\ndk-bundle\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin;%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\ndk-bundle;%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\platform-tools;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

My Android sdk is installed here (installed by Android Studio default):-

```
C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

and i installed NDK from android studio only which is present here

```
C:\Users\Gamer\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle
```

in the start it was saying can't find "make" then i searched make and find it here :-

```
%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\ndk-bundle\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin
```

after adding it in PATH now that make error does not comes up but the above error comes up

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ndk to your PATH variable.

Or try

```
ndk-build NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/path/to/your/Application.mk
```

Comment: what wrong in the patch i added :-  %ANDROID_SDK_HOME%\ndk-bundle;  it also redirects to same location

Comment: You need to install the ndk separately, it's not in the SDK.

Comment: i have installed NDK from the android studio and i can compile ndk c/c++ projects easily when make android apps,dont know how to build separately like the github page is saying